# Is "être début décembre" without a preposition grammatical?

Tags: grammaire, usage, indications-de-temps

"Bon, ok on est encore **début décembre**. Mais ne faisons pas comme si on ne le voyait pas venir tous les ans. Dans 22 jours tout piles, on déballe les cadeaux."

Isn't it more correct to word it "on est encore au début de décembre"?

Comment: One more thing bugging me, "Dans 22 jours tout piles". Isn't it supposed to be  "Dans 22 jours tout pile" with no accord?

Comment: I agree,  "pile" is an adverb . You can move it freely: *pile dans 22 jours*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how grammarians analyze this construction, but it's perfectly normal French. “*On est encore début décembre*” is idiomatic. “*On est encore au début de décembre*” is somewhat unidiomatic because, in late 20th/early 21st century French, it sounds stilted. This doesn't change if you use more formal language: “*Nous sommes encore début décembre*” is idiomatic, “*Nous sommes encore au début de décembre*” is perfectly comprehensible but sounds unnatural.

You can use “*au début de …*” to emphasize that it's still early, but then the sentence needs other changes: “*nous ne sommes qu'au début du mois de décembre*”. Expressions like “*au début de*” or “*à la fin de*” work with words like “*mois*” or “*année*” but not so much if you just use the name of the month or the year number. This is a matter of usage, not grammar.

French hasn't always been like this, but “*début décembre*” has been in use at least since the 19th century. “*Au début de décembre*” used to be idiomatic, but it went into decline around the middle of the 20th century, taken over by “*début décembre” in most usage and “*au début du mois de décembre*” when emphasis is needed. It's rather visible on [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9but+d%C3%A9cembre%2Cau+d%C3%A9but+de+d%C3%A9cembre%2Cd%C3%A9but+du+mois+de+d%C3%A9cembre&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cd%C3%A9but%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9but%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BD%C3%A9but%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9but%20D%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cau%20d%C3%A9but%20de%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bau%20d%C3%A9but%20de%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAu%20d%C3%A9but%20de%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bau%20d%C3%A9but%20de%20D%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cd%C3%A9but%20du%20mois%20de%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9but%20du%20mois%20de%20d%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%C3%A9but%20du%20mois%20de%20D%C3%A9cembre%3B%2Cc0) (I had to use “*début du mois de décembre*” without a leading *au* because Ngrams has a 5-word limit).

[image: début décembre,au début de décembre,début du mois de décembre]

The same construction works with month names and year numbers. I think the rule is that it takes a time span that works a little like a proper noun, without an article. If you can say “*en X*“ (where X is a time period) then you can also say “*début X*”, “*mi-X*” and “*fin X*”. ”*Courant X*“ is also possible, but rarer. It also works with business jargon like "*Q1*" (pronounced [ky.œ̃]), e.g. "*ce projet doit être livré fin Q1*" is a business anglicism for "*ce projet doit être livré à la fin du premier trimestre*" or "*... livré fin mars*", even though you can't say "<s>**en Q1*</s>".

> De mi-décembre à début janvier se situe kabengele ou nsafya-manika, nommé kyongwe aussi sur sa fin. [*Problèmes Sociaux Congolais*. In *Bulletin Trimestriel du Centre d'Étude des Problèmes Sociaux Indigènes*, 1873.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hTs8AAAAIAAJ&q=%22d%C3%A9but+janvier%22&dq=%22d%C3%A9but+janvier%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6s8D4meviAhWuzoUKHQ3pC9kQ6AEIXzAI)
>
> On a choisi quatre pins de même âge […]. L'un a été coupé à la fin de décembre, le second à la fin de janvier, le troisième à la fin de février, et le quatrième à la fin de mars. […] Ainsi, la résistance a été maxima pour l'arbre abattu fin décembre […]. On a obtenu des résultats entièrement semblables pour la durée et la solidité des pieux formés avec des tiges coupées les unes fin décembre, les autres à la fin de mars. [In *Journal d'agriculture, sciences, lettres et arts*, 1861.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=rqoTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA217&dq=%22fin+d%C3%A9cembre%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0jZKyoOviAhVOrxoKHfkTCZYQ6AEITTAF#v=onepage&q=%22fin%20d%C3%A9cembre%22&f=false)
>
> J’assume le retard et l’ouverture du théâtre fin 2020 ou début 2021. [Christophe Girard, déclaration à la presse, 2019](http://www.leparisien.fr/paris-75/paris-le-theatre-de-la-ville-va-se-faire-encore-attendre-21-01-2019-7993713.php)

---

Note that "**tout piles*" is unambiguously not grammatical. It should be "*tout pile*". "*Pile*" is an adverb, meaning "exactly".

Comment: Ouais, LBU14 scinde ça en deux. D'abord pour la préposition/article avant _fin/début/courant_ il dit : s'emploient sans ds. la langue commerciale et de là, dans la familière et même la langue écrite. (315) Ensuite, après ces mots, on dit : souvent suivis directement, et non seulement dans la langue commerciale. (354) Donc ce n'est pas G&G qui chialent. La BDL est moins nuancée, quoiqu'elle dit _certains suggèrent_.

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatical: in everyday language, you can use *début* or *fin* and omit the prepositions when mentioning a month or a year. It is not recommended, however, to use this in formal language.

> On part en vacances fin juillet.
>
> La prochaine réunion est prévue début 2020.

More details [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3440).

Comment: Why would it be not recommended in formal language? This is perfectly normal French.

Comment: C'est du français "normal" dans le sens où c'est évidemment tout à fait correct et usité en langage courant (dans les conversations, la presse, la correspondance commerciale, etc.), mais cela peut dénoter dans un registre soutenu (littérature, académie française, etc), où on trouvera plutôt la forme complète. C'est ce que conseille p.ex. Reverso: http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_34_les_noms_de_mois_annees_en_constuction_directe.shtml (mais à titre personnel, je pense en effet que c'est un usage tellement courant que dans un futur proche, cette recommandation est vouée à disparaitre).

Comment: C'est déjà dans l'usage soutenu. Comme souvent, certaines sources ont plusieurs générations de retard.

Comment: @Gilles: C'est marrant, l'un dit que c'est pas formel, l'autre que c'est dans l'usage soutenu… pour ma part il me semble que c'est dans l'usage formel, mais pas pour autant d'un registre soutenu.